# O que é e como funciona o objeto "Atomics" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics):

> O objeto `Atomics` fornece operações atômicas como métodos estáticos. Eles são usados com objetos `SharedArrayBuffer`.

Mas não me parece claro. Gostaria de saber o que é e como funciona esse objeto `Atomics` em JavaScript. Qual a sua finalidade e quando deve ser utilizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa Luiz,

Primeiro para entender o que o Atomics do JavaScript faz precisamos entender o que são operações atômicas em computação e para que elas existem.

### Concorrência, Paralelismo e condição de corrida

Primeira coisa pra entender as operações atômicas, a gente precisa entender que o nosso sistema operacional trabalha operando várias threads simultâneamente, e as vezes uma linha de código da gente simples como:

```
x = x + 5;
```

pode ser interrompida no meio do seu processamento e voltada a ser processada depois.

Acontece que imagina que duas threads distintas acessam esse recurso x, se uma thread A está executando essa operação, e é pausada, então uma thread b altera o valor de x no meio do processo, a thread a irá executar esta operação de maneira errada.

### Operações Atômicas

Dito isto, algumas linguagens de programação possuem operações atômicas, que são operações indivisíveis, aos quais o sistema operacional não poderá "pausar" e trocar de thread no meio dessas operações.

### Método Atomics do JavaScript

Em 2017 o JavaScript introduziu o `Shared Memory` e o `Atomics`, e assim por exemplo você pode utilizar o `SharedArrayBuffer` para compartilhar dados nessa memória compartilhada entre a sua `thread principal do JS` e `threads de web worker` por exemplo, aos quais se forem acessar o mesmo recurso simultâneamente, podem gerar a condição de corrida citada acima.

Portanto o `Atomics` trás uma série de métodos que você pode utilizar para tratar essa condição de corrida, fazendo com que estas operações que envolvem recursos compartilhados sejam atômicas, bloqueando o acesso de uma outra thread enquanto uma thread acessa este recurso.